# How do you marshall a parameterized type with JAX-WS / JAXB?

Tags: java, generics, jaxb, jax-ws, web-services

Consider the following classes (please assume public getter and setter methods for the private fields).

```
// contains a bunch of properties
public abstract class Person { private String name; }

// adds some properties specific to teachers
public class Teacher extends Person { private int salary; }

// adds some properties specific to students
public class Student extends Person { private String course; }

// adds some properties that apply to an entire group of people
public class Result<T extends Person> {
   private List<T> group;

   private String city;
   // ...
}
```

We might have the following web service implementation annotated as follows:

```
@WebService
public class PersonService {

    @WebMethod
    public Result<Teacher> getTeachers() { ... }

    @WebMethod
    public Result<Student> getStudents() { ... }
}
```

The problem is that JAXB appears to marshall the Result object as a `Result<Person>` instead of the concrete type. So the Result returned by getTeachers() is serialized as containing a `List<Person>` instead of `List<Teacher>`, and the same for getStudents(), mutatis mutandis.

Is this the expected behavior? Do I need to use @XmlSeeAlso on Person?

Thanks!

LES

Comment: can you give a resulting XML ?

Comment: i'm actually using a JAX-WS JSON plugin that returns JSON data. An example of getTeachers example would be: {city:"Memphis",group:[{name:"Johnny"}]} . That is, "salary" would not appear. The same for getStudents - it would like exactly like the previous example (course would not show up). I'm not on my dev box now which is why I can't post a real example of the WSDL or generated schema or XML from accessing the service via SOAP using SoapUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this one was rather tricky. It turns out that the version of jettison used by the jax-ws json plugin is a bit old (1.0-beta-1 IIRC). That particular version doesn't handle this case well (it crashes). If you do add the @XmlSeeAlso then the JSON marshalling will crash! Of course, this sucks!

I read on some forum (don't have the link - this is all from memory) that the jax-ws json plugin isn't actively maintained. If you try to 1) exclude the default jettison dependency from the jax-ws json depedency (assuming maven here) and add a newer version you get an error about JSONException not existing. Jax-ws json will NOT work with a newer version of jettison (I tried).

This is documented on another website (someone stated that they would like for someone to port jax-ws json to the latest jettison).

In the end, I switched to DWR for remoting. JAX-WS is best left for system-to-system (backend) integration. It's too heavy-weight for front-end stuff. DWR works AWESOMELY in this case.

Found link to forum I read: http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=384385 . Note that Collab.net is currently down for maintenance but they'll be back up soon.

As far as answering the general question (without the JAX-WS JSON plugin part), the answer is yes - you must use the @XmlSeeAlso annotation on the Person class. Otherwise the schema will only contain Person and not Teacher or Student elements. Only the elements defined in Person are marshalled without the @XmlSeeAlso annotation.

Comment: i see this post is two years old. what do you use currently for implementing a WebMethod with JSON?

Comment: i think jersey would be standard in the java verse? (if you want restful services). spring mvc makes this trivial too, just add ResponseBody annotations on the controller methods and specify the content-type to application/json on the RequestMapping annotation. and sometimes i use grails (though i'm not completely won oever).